# Why is there a drastic difference in timing to do the same integral between V 13.2 and 13.1?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, version-13.2

Could someone help me figure out why this integral <s>hangs</s> takes long time in V 13.2.1 (and V 13.2) but finishes instantly in V 13.1?

It took (798 seconds)  in V 13.2.1  and in V 13.1 it completes in less than one second. So something is way off. Did something change between V 13.1 and 13.2 to cause this? Here is the integral. Notice also that the result is different. In V 13.1 there is no complex term, but V 13.2.1 has complex in it. This might give a hint as why this drastic change in timing?  I verified that the result of V 13.1 is correct.

I have also just verified the result of V 13.2 to be *correct* after simplification. But it is much more complex and take much longer to do the same integral.

```
Integrate[(-2*Cot[x]^2 + Sin[x])/(1 + 5*Tan[x]^2)^(3/2), x]
```

Screen shots

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: @MichaelE2 the second one complete quickly due to caching. If you start new kernel, it does not complete quickly any more.

Comment: (I'd add that to the question so that people don't spend time chasing it down.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 I am not sure I understand what you want me to add to the question. But please feel free to add what you want to the end of the question, anything you feel will make it more clear. You could add your name to the edit if you wish.

Comment: I'll just write what I found out. It's not a complete answer, though. I think Daniel is the only one who might be able to say what's changed, and even then, tracking down how an edge shifted in an edge case may or may not be easy.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it. On more or less fresh kenel in 13.2.1 on Windows 10 `Timing[Integrate[(-2*Cot[x]^2 + Sin[x])/(1 + 5*Tan[x]^2)^(3/2), x]]` produces `{1.4375, (Csc[x] Sec[
     x] (196 - 164 Cos[2 x] - 9 Sin[x] - 
      4 ArcTan[(2 Sin[x])/Sqrt[-3 + 2 Cos[2 x]]] Sqrt[-3 + 2 Cos[2 x]]
        Sin[x] + Sin[3 x]))/(16 Sqrt[-2 + 3 Sec[x]^2 + 2 Tan[x]^2])}`.

Comment: @user64494 I do not know why you can't reproduce it. I can every time after I clear the kernel. You see the screen shot. This is very strange. I am also on windows 10 pro, V 13.2.1.   You might want to make make sure you did this from clean Kernel just after doing Quit[] in the cell above. Otherwise, I have no idea.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdVsC.png)

Comment: @Nasser: You are right. My above execution was in 13.1. Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I’ll check it when I get a chance.

Comment: There was some amount of code churn in the 13.2 development cycle for indefinite integrals involving trigs. One consequence is that examples like this degraded. Severely  (though to be fair, others improved substantially). This example at least is back in running order for version 13.3. The result is still not quite as concise as it was in 13.1, but it's acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First:

```
Quit[]
```

Then if the integral is computed twice, the second time is done quickly. The second time is fast even if the the first time is aborted (after a small wait).  Something must get initialized or cached in the first tenths of a second that allows `Integrate` to select relatively quickly the correct internal integrator the second time through.  I suppose that when it is initialized the first time, it is too late in the decision tree to select the correct internal integrator.

```
TimeConstrained[
 Integrate[(-2*Cot[x]^2 + Sin[x])/(1 + 5*Tan[x]^2)^(3/2),
  x], 0.5];
 
Integrate[(-2*Cot[x]^2 + Sin[x])/(1 + 5*Tan[x]^2)^(3/2), 
  x] // AbsoluteTiming
(*
{0.315578, 
 (Csc[x] Sec[
   x] (196 - 164 Cos[2 x] - 9 Sin[x] - 
    4 ArcTan[(2 Sin[x])/Sqrt[-3 + 2 Cos[2 x]]] Sqrt[-3 + 2 Cos[2 x]]
      Sin[x] + Sin[3 x]))/(16 Sqrt[-2 + 3 Sec[x]^2 + 2 Tan[x]^2])}
*)
```

Comment: Great find Michael !

Comment: may be what happens is this:   First time:  Integrate choose path A, which is the _wrong_ path, but on path A it loads some code which is only loaded along path A. Then path A is stuck because wrong path and takes long time.  Now on second try on same kernel, the thing that was loaded, now helps Intergrate see that path A is wrong before even going along that path, and choose the better path B, which finishes fast. So whatever code was loaded along path A, should have been loaded before choosing which path  to go on?

Comment: @Nasser Yes, that's basically my guess, too.

Answer (score 2):

Its an example, how inefficient the integration algorithms of standard integrals are implemented.

The standard substitution $t\to \tan \frac{x}{2}$ yields an result in 0.7 s

```
  Module[{sq},sq=(dx (-2*Cot[x]^2+Sin[x])/(1+5*Tan[x]^2)^(3/2))^2 /.
   {dx->(2 dt)/(1+t^2), Sin[x]-> t/(1+t^2), Tan[x]->t/(1-t^2), Cot[x]:> (1-(t^2) )/t};
sq==Sqrt[sq]//PowerExpand; 
Integrate[sq,t]/.{t->Tan[x/2], dt->1}
     //FunctionExpand]//Timing
```

with an imprintable output
$$\left\{0.640625,4 \left(-1932 \tan ^{-1}\left(\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{\frac{5}{2 \left(\sqrt{5}+3\right)}} \left(1754 \sqrt{5}+16655\right) \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}+3}} \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{8} \sqrt{\frac{5}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+3\right)} \left(1754 \sqrt{5}-16655\right) \tan ^{-1}\left(\sqrt{\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{5}+3\right)} \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)-\frac{1932 \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{\tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1}-\frac{8 \left(\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-96\right)}{3 \left(\tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1\right)^2}+\frac{32 \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{3 \left(\tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1\right)^3}-\frac{5 \left(3508 \tan ^3\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+640 \tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+5757 \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-240\right)}{8 \left(\tan ^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+3 \tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1\right)}+\frac{25 \left(297 \tan ^3\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+80 \tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+198 \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+20\right)}{4 \left(\tan ^4\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+3 \tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1\right)^2}+4 \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\frac{1}{3} 4 \cot ^3\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+84 \cot \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-2048 \log \left(\tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+1\right)+5 \sqrt{5} \left(41 \sqrt{5}-25\right) \log \left(2 \tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)+\sqrt{5}+3\right)+5 \sqrt{5} \left(41 \sqrt{5}+25\right) \log \left(2 \tan ^2\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-\sqrt{5}+3\right)-4 \log \left(\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right)\right)\right\}$$

Comment: The output (anti-derivative) has $dt^2$ in it. It should only have $x$ in it. What is $dt^2$?  Here is screen shot. V 13.2.1  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5JqH.png)

Comment: I also noticed what you show in your answer as output in Latex, does not have the $dt^2$. This is strange. Are you using V 13.2 also? or V 13.1?

Comment: Missing dt->1 in {t->Tan[x/2]  after Integrate.  The explicit differential in Leibniz notation has to be introduced in order to transform the integration measure correctly.

Comment: Ok, I replaced $dt$ by $1$ in the result. But your anti-derivative does not verify. i.e. if you differentiate the antiderivative you obtained and compare it with the integrand, it looks different. It is not even a shifted version to account for constant of integration. Did you verify it yourself? I am not able to.  ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfPVx.png)

Comment: code for the above `out = Module[{sq}, 
    sq = (dx (-2*Cot[x]^2 + Sin[x])/(1 + 5*Tan[x]^2)^(3/2))^2 /.
      {dx -> (2 dt)/(1 + t^2), Sin[x] -> t/(1 + t^2), 
       Tan[x] -> t/(1 - t^2), Cot[x] :> (1 - (t^2))/t};
    sq == Sqrt[sq] // PowerExpand;
    Integrate[sq, t] /. {t -> Tan[x/2], dt -> 1} // FunctionExpand] //
    Timing;
antiDiff = D[out[[2]], x] // Simplify;
integrand = (-2*Cot[x]^2 + Sin[x])/(1 + 5*Tan[x]^2)^(3/2);
Plot[{antiDiff, integrand}, {x, -3, 3}]`

Comment: It is possible your method just needs small adjustment. I do not know now.

Answer (score 2):

This has been fixed in V 13.3. Now it is back fast

```
Timing[Integrate[(-2*Cot[x]^2 + Sin[x])/(1 + 5*Tan[x]^2)^(3/2), x]]

{0.92357,-(((-3+2 Cos[2 x])^(3/2) (-1+2 Cot[x]^2 Csc[x]) Sin[x]^2 (-2 ArcSinh[2 Sin[x]] (4+Csc[x]^2)+(-2+164 Csc[x]-3 Csc[x]^2+16 Csc[x]^3) Sqrt[1+4 Sin[x]^2]) Tan[x])/(2 Sqrt[-(3-2 Cos[2 x])^2] (5+Cot[x]^2) (4+4 Cos[2 x]-3 Sin[x]+Sin[3 x]) Sqrt[1+5 Tan[x]^2]))}
```

[image]